# How to implement HttpClient in Xamarin.Forms applications using better CPU and Memory?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I am bit confused about all those problems and workarounds of httpclient usage in xamarin.forms. I would like to summarize my understanding and hesitations/questions

1. **Disposing every time vs Singleton HttpClient and Static Client:** It is said that dont use using around httpClient and use singleton implementation as stated in [this](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications) article

Wrong;

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    //Some settings
});
```

Correct:

```
public class HttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpService()
    {
        _httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
    }
```

Here the first question, if we dont use `static` what is the advantage of this?
 Because HttpService will start a new client for each thread, not? If we use static client, will this cause any memory cycle? 
  Xamarin forms is very fragile about static dependency, if you are holding a static value inside a ViewModel and ViewModel is coupled with View using Freshmvvm, Prism etc., usually View wont be disposed and instance remains in the memory and causes memory leak even after popping the page.

2. **DNS changes problem:** it looks like that there is a problem to use singleton HttpClient whenever DNs changes as described [here](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html). How to overcome this problem in a xamarin.forms application? I dont see any ServicePointManager defined in .net standard 2.0. Do I really have to worry about this?
3. **ReadAsStreamAsync vs ReadAsStringAsync** when getting response. Does it make a big difference to use ReadAsStreamAsync? and is there any side effect to use as stream?
4. Should we dispose HttpResponseMessage with a using like below?

   using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
                   {
                       if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                       {
                          //Do something
                       }
                       else
                       {
                         //Do something
                       }
                   }

Finally my Class looks like as below; Do you see any problem with this?
proxy setting are described in [this](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/httpclient-and-proxy-76835c784eab) article

```
namespace myApp
{

    public class HttpService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private JsonSerializer _serializer = new JsonSerializer();        

        public HttpService()
        {

            if (client == null)
            {
                try
                    {
                        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
                        {
                            Proxy = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IProxyInfoProvider>().GetProxySettings()
                        };
                        client = new HttpClient(handler);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }              
            } 
        }


        public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken=default(CancellationToken))
        {
            T returnObject = default(T);
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);

            try
            {
               using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri,cancellationToken))
                {   
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                   //Handle error
                }
                else
                {
                    returnObject = await getReturnObject<T>(response);
                }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return returnObject;
        }




        public async Task<T> getReturnObject<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            T returnObject = default(T);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
                using (JsonTextReader json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    returnObject = _serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
                }
                //string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
            }

            return returnObject;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: that should be a static constructor in the second snippet of `HttpService`. Both of those snippets basically do the same thing

Comment: @Nkosi so you suggest to change HttpService with static constructor and HttpClient static as well in this case. what will be the advantage and can this cause any memory leak if i use it as static?

Comment: I am saying that the example where you say it is correct way to use client is wrong.

Comment: The second snippet does not prevent you from creating a second instance of HttpService which will create a second instance of HttpClient. If you want a true singleton. here's a nice in depth article on to do it: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @jgoldberger thank you for sharing. I was confused with this article, see "reuse your httpclient" part. http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications

Beside that if I define, client as static, do I have to worry any memory leaks or i can assume that it is safe as it will be disposed after usage is completed.

Comment: A static member will remain in the heap memory for the life of the application. This is not a memory leak as it is always accessible. A memory leak occurs when you have an instantiated object that you no longer have a reference to so that you can no longer use it, access it, or dispose of it, but it is still in memory. So no, you don't have to worry about a memory leak, but the instance will stay in memory until you explicitly dispose it, or until the app is terminated. But you will only ever have the one instance, so not a big worry that it lives for the life of the app.